# How to fix "xvinfo: Unable to open display /private/tmp/.../org.macosforge.xquartz:0" error?

Tags: macos, install, homebrew, bug, x11

I run `xvinfo` and get

```
xvinfo:  Unable to open display /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.D2FFj2I3es/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
```

I do not understand. No previous google match for it.

Something wrong with X11.

The command `brew doctor` gives

```
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: Some directories in /usr/local/share/man aren't writable.
This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed
by Homebrew. If a brew tries to add locale information to one of these
directories, then the install will fail during the link step.
You should probably `chown` them:

    /usr/local/share/man/de
    /usr/local/share/man/de/man1
    /usr/local/share/man/mann

Warning: Broken symlinks were found. Remove them with `brew prune`:
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.07/Resource/Font/logo10.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.07/Resource/Font/logo8.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.07/Resource/Font/logo9.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.07/Resource/Font/logobf10.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.07/Resource/Font/logod10.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.07/Resource/Font/logosl10.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.07/Resource/Font/logosl8.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.07/Resource/Font/logosl9.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.07/Resource/Font/manfnt.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.07/Resource/Font/wasy10.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.07/Resource/Font/wasy5.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.07/Resource/Font/wasy6.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.07/Resource/Font/wasy7.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.07/Resource/Font/wasy8.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.07/Resource/Font/wasy9.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.07/Resource/Font/wasyb10.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.10/Resource/Font/logo10.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.10/Resource/Font/logo8.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.10/Resource/Font/logo9.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.10/Resource/Font/logobf10.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.10/Resource/Font/logod10.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.10/Resource/Font/logosl10.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.10/Resource/Font/logosl8.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.10/Resource/Font/logosl9.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.10/Resource/Font/manfnt.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.10/Resource/Font/wasy10.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.10/Resource/Font/wasy5.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.10/Resource/Font/wasy6.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.10/Resource/Font/wasy7.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.10/Resource/Font/wasy8.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.10/Resource/Font/wasy9.pfb
  /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.10/Resource/Font/wasyb10.pfb

Warning: Your XQuartz (2.7.5) is outdated
Please install XQuartz 2.7.7:
  https://xquartz.macosforge.org

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libtk8.6.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
    /usr/local/include/fakemysql.h
    /usr/local/include/fakepq.h
    /usr/local/include/fakesql.h
    /usr/local/include/itcl.h
    /usr/local/include/itcl2TclOO.h
    /usr/local/include/itclDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/itclInt.h
    /usr/local/include/itclIntDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/itclMigrate2TclCore.h
    /usr/local/include/itclTclIntStubsFcn.h
    /usr/local/include/mysqlStubs.h
    /usr/local/include/node/ares.h
    /usr/local/include/node/ares_version.h
    /usr/local/include/node/nameser.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node_buffer.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node_internals.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node_object_wrap.h
    /usr/local/include/node/node_version.h
    /usr/local/include/node/openssl/opensslconf.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/ngx-queue.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/stdint-msvc2008.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/tree.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-bsd.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-darwin.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-linux.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-sunos.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-unix.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv-private/uv-win.h
    /usr/local/include/node/uv.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8-debug.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8-preparser.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8-profiler.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8-testing.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8.h
    /usr/local/include/node/v8stdint.h
    /usr/local/include/node/zconf.h
    /usr/local/include/node/zlib.h
    /usr/local/include/odbcStubs.h
    /usr/local/include/pqStubs.h
    /usr/local/include/tcl.h
    /usr/local/include/tclDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/tclOO.h
    /usr/local/include/tclOODecls.h
    /usr/local/include/tclPlatDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/tclThread.h
    /usr/local/include/tclTomMath.h
    /usr/local/include/tclTomMathDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/tdbc.h
    /usr/local/include/tdbcDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/tdbcInt.h
    /usr/local/include/tk.h
    /usr/local/include/tkDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/tkPlatDecls.h

Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tcl.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tk.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/xml2po.pc

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
    /usr/local/lib/libtclstub8.6.a
    /usr/local/lib/libtkstub8.6.a

Warning: Some installed formula are missing dependencies.
You should `brew install` the missing dependencies:

    brew install pcre

Run `brew missing` for more details.

Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin
This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of those
provided by Homebrew. The following tools exist at both paths:

    2to3
    2to3-2.7
    easy_install
    easy_install-2.7
    idle
    idle2.7
    pydoc
    pydoc2.7
    python
    python-config
    python2.7
    python2.7-config
    pythonw
    pythonw2.7
    R
    Rscript
    smtpd.py
    smtpd2.7.py

Consider setting your PATH so that /usr/local/bin
occurs before /usr/bin. Here is a one-liner:
    echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

In $HOME/.bash_profile, I have `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/local/sbin` but `echo $PATH` gives `/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin`. Running `hash` but no change in $PATH. Probably, PATH issue.

**How can I fix this xvinfo error in Yosemite 10.10.3?**
My Macbook air is mid-2013.

Comment: did you run `brew doctor` after installing the formula?

Comment: I'd follow the good `brew doctor`'s advice and update XQuartz first.

Comment: Here’s my `$PATH` as it stands in my `.bash_profile`, running homebrew as well (I have my own bin located at `~/bin`, hence the appended ending). `export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$HOME/bin`

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the question. `xvinfo` is part of XQuartz. It has nothing to do with `xvid`. `xvid` is just a library for compressing and decompressing video and audio files. What is it you are trying to accomplish? From everything you've posted here it looks like xvid is installing successfully.

Comment: Problem now solved! Fixing brew doctor's advices solved the problem. Still, however, I did not manage to solve the PATH issue. I have files .bashrc, .bash_profile and .profile where sourcing contents of .bashrc to .bash_profile if such a file exists (and it does). File .profile is nearly empty.

Comment: @Masi Nope, not problem solved. `xvid` and `xvinfo` aren't related. :) Also, the polite thing to do if someone gives you a solution in a comment is to ask them to post their solution as a proper answer so they can get recognition for it.

Comment: @IanC. Can do it if he wants. I did not want to bother him becaues he initially send it only as a comment. I deleted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `brew doctor` output you posted there are two things you should do:

1. Install the latest XQuartz:

   ```
   Warning: Your XQuartz (2.7.5) is outdated
   Please install XQuartz 2.7.7:
     https://xquartz.macosforge.org
   ```
2. Make sure `/usr/local/bin` appears before `/usr/bin` in your `PATH` so Homebrew-installed utils are found before default versions of the tools:

   ```
   Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin
   This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of those
   provided by Homebrew. The following tools exist at both paths:

       2to3
       2to3-2.7
       easy_install
       easy_install-2.7
       idle
       idle2.7
       pydoc
       pydoc2.7
       python
       python-config
       python2.7
       python2.7-config
       pythonw
       pythonw2.7
       R
       Rscript
       smtpd.py
       smtpd2.7.py

   Consider setting your PATH so that /usr/local/bin
   occurs before /usr/bin. Here is a one-liner:
       echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
   ```

You can do the rest of things recommended in `brew doctor` but those two things are at the heart of your problem.

Comment: I would also remove /opt/local/sbin from your path as that is Macports and that and Homebre don't work easily together